# Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' <using password: YES>

Tags: mysql

I'm getting an error:
`mysqladmin.exe: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'`

I tried to grant privileges

```
mysqladmin.exe grant all ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost'
```

I'm trying to create a database with:

```
CD C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
mysqladmin.exe create database comersus -p
```

I just installed MySQL 5.5.27.2
I created a user called myuser
I'm working in XP Pro sp3

Please let me know the correct command line to 
(I think I need to grant permission first)
Create a database file.

Answer (score 13):

Try running the mysql command with the following option:

```
C:> mysql -u root
```

This specifies the "root" MySQL user when you connect.

Because you didn't specify any user, it defaulted to an "anonymous" 
(unnamed) user. On Windows, the username is set to "ODBC" for some reason 
unknown to me.

Read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html) page (part of the tutorial) about connecting to the server.

And read the section of the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html) starting at the link below, to learn more 
than you ever thought possible about users and privileges.

Comment: I'm running this command: mysql -u username -p userpswd -h localhost -e 'create database Databasename' --tee=Run.log --comments --debug-info  I have used the actual names in place of username, userpswd, databasename

Comment: I get a screen full of help messages and values.  I get nothing in the run.log and no debug info.

Comment: I have been working on this for two days.  I have read all that you have suggested.  This should have taken me 10 min to create a database. The output doesn't tell me if it worked or error'ed out. If you know would you please just tell me the exact command line I should use.

Comment: mysql -u root gives me this error 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: No)'

Comment: Did you try specifying a password?

Comment: adding a user does get me into mysql.  mysql -u root -p

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue and find my solution.

Go to path MySQL/data. Under this folder check for (.err) ERR file. 
There may be temporary password generated as below.

**[Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: _yJU=h0P!E<0**

Hope it helps some one.

Comment: YES. Finally a solution that WORKS. I was not even able to connect to mysql in the first place to reconfigure anything. What a mess tho. I haven't even started with mysql and already I am getting cryptic initializations that you need to read the developers' minds to get started. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks. it works for me too. Also, after getting into connection, one could reset this temp password by running query:
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_NEW_PASSWORD';`

see [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#:~:text=In%20the%20mysql%20client%2C%20tell,that%20you%20want%20to%20use.) doc.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a database, Grant permissions and flush privileges to activate the new permissions in a batch file:

Start of MySQLrun.bat

```
    @echo off
    :: I had to use the root user because the user I created didn't have any authority 
    set user=root
    ::set user=MyUser
    :: When I first installed MySQL I set a password
    set password=MyPassword
    set host=localhost

    CD C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin
    :: Create a database file
    :: The log will be in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

    mysql  -h %host% -u %user% -p%password% < c:\Dnload\MySQLCommands.sql --tee=Run.log --comments --debug-info --verbose
    cmd
```

End of MySQLrun.bat

The bat file runs the commands in the MySQLCommands.sql file:

Start of MySQLCommands.sql

```
    drop database if exists MyDatabaseFileName;
    CREATE DATABASE MyDatabaseFileName;
    # An example of how to GRANT ALL privileges to a user 
    #grant all ON mydatabasefilename.* TO 'Myuser'@localhost identified by 'MyPassword';
    # GRANT INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, SELECT ON databasename.* TO ‘username’@'localhost’   IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’;
    # To activate the new permissions, issue the following command:
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    #  How to log in to a specific database on a MySQL server:
show grants for 'MyUser'@'localhost'
```

End of MySQLCommands.sql

Please Note:  All usernames, Database names and passwords are case sensitive.

There are many ways to create a database.  This is just one of them.

Answer (score 1):

My case was a dumb mistake I typed **mysql u -jim -p**